# Forms Recognizer - Unable to train forms in subfolder with label file

Tags: azure-cognitive-services

We have multiple different forms to be trained in a model. We have created separate subfolders for each and have created the label files for each of the forms in their respective folder. When we train the model with "IncludeSubfolder" as true" and "uselabelfile" as true.. we get the following error

```
{"modelInfo":
{"modelId": "9d63e55b-23a5-43a4-a845-17864b35549d",
"status": "invalid",
"createdDateTime": "2020-04-03T11:15:14Z",
"lastUpdatedDateTime": "2020-04-03T11:15:14Z"},

"trainResult":
{"averageModelAccuracy": 0.0,
"errors":
[{"code": "1001", "message": "Not supported case of IncludeSubFolders and UseLabelFile set to true simultaneously."}]}}
```

any idea about this error ?

Answer (score 0):

You need to direct the API to a sub-folder as stated in the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cognitive-services/form-recognizer/quickstarts/python-labeled-data#set-up-training-data) thus, setting `includeSubFolders = true` is not possible with `useLabelFile = true` simultaneously, therefore the error you are receiving!

The documentation states the following:

> The labeled data feature has special input requirements beyond those
>   needed to train a custom model.
>
> Make sure all the training documents are of the same format. If you
>   have forms in multiple formats, organize them into sub-folders based
>   on common format. When you train, you'll need to direct the API to a
>   sub-folder.

Notice:

> When you train, you'll need to direct the API to a sub-folder.